# Como eu crio um CSV no C, incrementando o primeiro número?

Tags: c

Gerei esse csv:

```
1;0
2;0
2;0
2;0
2;1
2;2
2;2
2;2
2;2
2;3

...
```

Como obtenho desse arquivo o primeiro número de cada linha para incrementá-lo?

E tem como a primeira linha não ser pulada?

```
int gerarRelatorioHash(int colisoes) {
     FILE *pont_arq;

     pont_arq = fopen("relatorio.csv", "r+");

     if(pont_arq == NULL) {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
        return 1;
    }

    int qtd;
    fscanf(pont_arq, "%d", &qtd);
    qtd++;

    fseek(pont_arq, 0, SEEK_END);\
    fprintf(pont_arq, "\n%d;%d", qtd,colisoes);

    fclose(pont_arq);
    printf("Dados gravados com sucesso!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

A ideia que o `qtd` seja um contador a qual a cada linha que ele pule ele faça uma `qtd++` e o segundo parâmetro seja o que foi passado.

Exemplo de como deveria ter ficado:

```
1;0
2;0
3;0
4;0
5;1
6;2
7;2
8;2
9;2
10;3
....
```

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar o exemplo do seu arquivo com mais linhas para ficar mais claro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de alterar o arquivo de entrada, você pode simplesmente convertê-lo, gravando um arquivo de saída com o novo conteúdo, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINHA_MAX_LEN  (256)

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int n = 0;
    int seq, val;
    char linha[ LINHA_MAX_LEN + 1 ];
    FILE * in = NULL;
    FILE * out = NULL;

    in = fopen( argv[1], "r");

    if(!in)
    {
        printf("Erro abrindo arquivo de entrada para leitura.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    out = fopen( argv[2], "w");

    if(!out)
    {
        printf("Erro abrindo arquivo de saida para gravacao.\n");
        fclose(in);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Para cada linha do arquivo de entrada */
    while( fgets( linha, sizeof(linha), in ) )
    {
        /* Incrementa contador de linhas */
        n++;

        /* Interpreta linha lida */
        sscanf( linha, "%d;%d\n", &seq, &val );

        /* Grava a linha com novo sequencial no arquivo de saida */
        fprintf( out, "%d;%d\n", n, val );
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    printf("Linhas Processadas: %d\n", n );

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
$ ./enumerar relatorio.csv saida.csv
Linhas Processadas: 10
```

Entrada (`relatorio.csv`):

```
1;0
2;0
2;0
2;0
2;1
2;2
2;2
2;2
2;2
2;3
```

Saída (`saida.csv`):

```
1;0
2;0
3;0
4;0
5;1
6;2
7;2
8;2
9;2
10;3
```